# Pascal Progress Status

Tags: freepascal

I am trying to emulate a progress loading status in free pascal but i am having difficulty trying to achieve an output that looks like a loading progression status.
The code i have for this is:

```
percent := 0;
Writeln('Loading');   
Repeat
 Write('(',percent,'%)');
 percent = percent + 1;
 Delay(50);
Until percent > 100;
```

But the output turns out like this:

```
Loading(0%)(1%)(2%)
```

When i want it to look like this:

```
Loading(0%) -> Loading(1%) {The percent variable going up like a loading status}
```

I only want the percent variable to change in the loop. I've looked over the delete and insert procedures but i don't think it is what i am looking for.

Comment: http://www.at.freepascal.org/packages/ncurses.html

Comment: There was a question very similar to this on codegolf. Here is my [answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/101344/5116) in pascal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use backspace to go back and write over.  Like so:

```
uses Crt;
var percent: integer;
begin
  percent := 0;
  Write('Loading ');
  Repeat
   Write('(',percent:3,'%)'#8#8#8#8#8#8);
   percent := percent + 1;
   Delay(50);
  Until percent > 100;
end.
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what i was looking for

Comment: @LeCarloVC There are also several techniques: 1) Write carriage return (CR) without line feed (LF): `Write(#13); Write('(',percent,'%)');` 2) Use [VT100 Escape sequences](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences-vt-100.php) `Write(#27'[5D'); {Move cursor left 5 positions} Write('(',percent,'%)');` PS: Not sure that it is compatible with Windows CMD. PPS: You can use `Sleep` from `SysUtils` unit instead of `Delay` from `Crt`.